# cURL is_file function for URLs

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to create a simple is_file type function that works with a URL:

```
function isFileUrl($url){
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // don't want it rendered to browser
  curl_exec($ch);

  if(curl_errno($ch)){
    $isFile = false;
  }
  else {
    $isFile = true;
  }
  curl_close($ch);
  return $isFile;
}

if(isFileUrl('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png')==true){
  echo 'TRUE';
} else {
  echo 'FALSE';
}
```

Works with the `curl_setopt` removed, but renders the content (image url) to the browser, which I don't want. What am I missing? I've [checked this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252179/equivalent-is-file-function-for-urls), but couldn't make it work in my context. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean `don't want it rendered to browser`?

Comment: Without the `curl_setopt` line there, if I call the function in an if statement `if(isFileUrl('http://www.image.url.jpg')===true){}` it renders the url (an image hosted online) to the page if true and `The specified request cannot be executed from current Application Pool` if false. I don't want that, only the outputted booleans.

Comment: So, does it work *with* the `url_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` line?  You say it "works" without it, but you never say what happens with that line.

Comment: @Rocket always returns false with that line in there. Updated question with how I am calling it.

Comment: I just tested this code on my server, and it worked fine.

Comment: Maybe you want CURLOPT_VERBOSE set to FALSE.

Comment: @enapupe: Isn't that `FALSE` be default?

Comment: @enapupe verbose didn't make a difference

Comment: I don't know.. actually I did not get your problem.
what you want to check is if the HTTP header returns 200 (OK) with a content-type of an image kind?

Comment: If it returns `false` that means that there was a cURL error!  Why not try to `echo curl_error($ch);`?

Comment: with the exact code above, if I change the url extention from .png to .pngf for example, it is not giving me true & false respectivaly as expected.

Comment: echo-ing returns to page `SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.` Perhaps there is a better method to check whether image exists?

Comment: @John: Try setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`

Comment: @Rocket Verifypeer fixes the false issue, but renders the image or a 404 to the browser.

Comment: @John: You need to keep the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` there too.

Comment: @Rocket that is returning true/true with returntransfer and verifypeer there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is a HTTP header check to see if it is a valid (200) url and it is related to an image (content-type === image/jpg, image/png, etc).
The following code might be a start:

```
function getHTTPStatus($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => false
    ));
    curl_exec($ch);
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch);
    return $http_status;
}

$img = getHTTPStatus($url);
$images = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'etc');
if($img['http_code'] === 200 && in_array($img['content_type'], $images)) {
   //it is an image, do stuff
 }
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` might be the solution to the issue he's having :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat I don't think a SSL issue is any way related to his main goal.

Comment: In a comment, he said that `curl_error` showed `SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.`.

Comment: This returns false/false also.

Comment: No @John, it returns the http header for the requested URL, it's not a matter of true/false.

Comment: I'm getting undefined var as $url is outside the function. Easy fix but I'll go with dragoste's method as it fulfills my need. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $url is the URL that you hardcoded in your example..It is the same thing, he is using a shortcut way to get the http headers. Also, your question was poorly formed and you were lucky to get a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Why won't you use [get_headers()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) function? It's design for such things.

Simple example can look like this:

```
function isFile($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    if($headers && strpos($headers[0], '200') !== false) { //response code 200 means that url is fine
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also check content-type or any other header, that you want.

Comment: That's good, I didn't know that we had this function... I would add a content_type verification and remove the return false.. return false is implicit.

Comment: You're welcome John. @enapupe, I didn't know it earlier too. Just found it. ;)

Comment: @dragoste gave the accept to enapupe, only because it utilizes the cURL method per the original question. Your answer deserves it also +1.

Answer (score 0):

(Self answer/summary)

Both Dragoste and Enapupe's answer work. Based on Enapupe's answer, I wrapped it into an all encompassing function and added an optional file type parameter. Hope it helps someone...

```
function isFileUrl($url, $type=''){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => false
    ));
    curl_exec($ch);
    $gh = curl_getinfo($ch);

    if($type!==''){
      // add types here (see http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full for list)
      if($type=='img'){
        $typeArr = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
      }
      elseif($type=='pdf'){
        $typeArr = array('application/pdf');
      }
      elseif($type=='html'){
        $typeArr = array('text/html');
      }

      if($gh['http_code'] === 200 && in_array($gh['content_type'], $typeArr)){
        $trueFalse = true;
      }
      else {
        $trueFalse = false;
      }

    }
    else {
      if($gh['http_code'] === 200){
        $trueFalse = true;
      }
      else {
        $trueFalse = false;
      }
    }
    return $trueFalse;
}

//test - param 1 is URL, param 2 (optional) can be img|pdf|html
if(isFileUrl('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png', 'img')==true){
  // do stuff
  echo 'TRUE';
}
else {
  echo 'FALSE';
}
```